# What is the difference between a straight line and a linear equation?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The books I am reading do not make clear distinction between the two. Also for understanding line I need to know basics of Geometry, similarly what prior knowledge is useful before one can understand linear equations?

Comment: When you visualize the set of points that satisfy a linear equation, the result is a straight line.

Comment: The graph of any linear function correspond to a line in the cartesian plane. Any line can be represented algebraically as a linear function or lineal equation.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @adriannaranjo. I also wanted to know whether looking at Cartesian plane as different positions in space might help develop an intuitive understanding of linear equation, sort of ground work before we actually start understanding linear equations. I for some reason don't want to approach linear equations as something that graphs a straight line on Cartesian plane. Although name suggests that precisely but still I was hoping I can approach linear equations on their own without having to refer to "straight line". Hope you get my point...

Answer (score 1):

When there is a direct relation between $x,y$ we have $ y =m x. $ This is a straight line passing through the origin.This is direct proportional dependence.

In a relationship $ y=mx+c$  the graph does not pass through the origin. At start $x=0,$ there is already a constant value available.

Both are linear in their relationship between the two variables and their graphs are represented by a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

In the plane the two are pretty much the same concept. More strictly speaking, a linear equation is one way of characterizing the set of points which make up a given line. There are other ways, e.g. using starting point and direction vector.

In higher dimensions things change: a line will always be the geometric concept of a one-dimensional affine subspace, while a linear equation will describe a hyperplane, a subspace one dimension less than the containing space.